# SSRS - Percentage Totals Row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to build an SSRS report that has a column based on a percentage:

```
AgentSales   AgentCommission       Commission
20           .25                   5 
33           .12                   3.96
46           .76                   34.96
Totals:       99                   [Unknown Calculation]
```

However, where I am having problems is I need to get what would be the totals column?  How would I calculate the Commission so that the number shown in [Unknown Calculation] to display what I assume would be the average commission?

Commission column is simply AgentSales * AgentCommission.  The total commission wouldn't be a SUM(Commission), but would more or less be the average commission for all agents.

Comment: Hi. In this particular example, what would be formula for `[Unknown Calculation]`, or average commission? Row 1 commission is 25, row 2 is 15.68 and row 3 is 1,222.2, so is it safe to say `[Unknown calculation]` value is (25 + 15.68 + 1,222.2) / 3 ?

Comment: My apologies, but Row1 commission is 5 (from 20 * .25).   The commission is simply AgentSales * AgentCommission.  What I put in parenthesis is the formula used to get the Commission.  I guess I should have been more clear in my original question

Comment: Well, actually it was clear. My mistake, I should have thought a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to calculate the **weighted** average commission then I would calculate it like this..

[image]

---

**Expression 1**: is simple as per your sample.

```
=Fields!AgentSales.Value * Fields!AgentCommission.Value
```

---

Expression 2: is the sum of the results of expression 1

```
=SUM(Fields!AgentSales.Value * Fields!AgentCommission.Value)
```

---

Expression 3: is the expression 2 divided by the sum of agent sales

```
=(SUM(Fields!AgentSales.Value * Fields!AgentCommission.Value))
 /
 SUM(Fields!AgentSales.Value)
```

---

The other cells should be self explanatory...

When we run the report we get the following.

[image]

If this is not what you wanted, then please edit your question to show the desired result and how you arrived at that result.

---

**EDIT AFTER UPDATE FROM OP**

If you want the cell marked "2" in my sample to be an average of the values above then simpley change it to

```
=AVG(Fields!AgentSales.Value * Fields!AgentCommission.Value)
```

Comment: I have edited my original question.  The issue isn't with getting the Commission in the rows, but the "Total Commission" on the last line.  The Total Commission isn't simply a SUM(Commission), but it would be the Average Commission for all agents.